# Landscape 2D CADD program

Tags: landscaping

I have used dynascape as a program when drawing for a non profit organization.  Since I volunteer my time and do not use the program for commercial or profit I simply can't afford the cost of the program and subscription.  I have used the student version for the past two years.  Any recommendations on what I could use.  My drawings are simple and in no need of color or 3D.

Comment: shoot! Marcia, I commented below the next answer. The comment was meant for you to consider and should have been placed here.  I apologize!

Answer (score 3):

If you feel comfortable using vector editing software, which is quite similar to CAD software (such as Adobe Illustrator or Corel) you could give Inkscape a try. It is free.

I have never tried, though, because being a professional designer I have a paid subscription of Adobe Illustrator. I use Adobe Illustrator to plan my garden.

Comment: Ah, so you're a professional designer, gtk.

Comment: @musser: and web programmer : )

Comment: Drawing by hand allows our human brains to 'see' the site and design considerations far better than cutting and pasting with a computer.  Computers are certainly faster and perhaps if I had been trained from the beginning on a computer to design landscapes, parks, building site drainage, freeways I'd be more hesitant to say you'd do better by hand.  One has got to be able to think in 3D to design anything.  Drawing by hand enables that ability to become honed.  Otherwise, I'd worry I was doing a substandard job that would end up costing way more, esp. with maintenance.